# Letsencrypt not working for domain on Server/IP 1 and for subdomain on Server/IP 2 *using A and AAAA records

Tags: dns, lets-encrypt, caa

Letsencrypt not working for domain on Server/IP 1 and  for subdomain on Server/IP 2 *using A and AAAA records

So we have 2 servers, 1 live and 1 staging

- live has multidomain cert for non-www and www using Letsencrypt
- live is hosted on server 1 with IP 1
- staging is hosted on staging.* on server server 2 with IP 2
- Problem: letsencrypt is not letting us generate SSL on server 2 with IP 2

**Question**: How can we solve the problem where letsencrypt is not letting us generate SSL on server 2 with IP 2?

Comment: What exactly "not letting us" means, do you get some error?

Comment: Servfail for subdomain caa. Caa was set for main domain without www. assumed all child subdomains would inherit but this does not seem the case

Comment: CAA was set at the rootdomain following https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/ as `domain.com.    14400   IN      CAA     0 issue "letsencrypt.org"` when I dig to `domain.com` I get CAA records, when I do the same for `staging.domain.com` I get no results. According to the spec CAA should be obtained from the main domain if not set on the subdomain. Or am I missing something?